# EXCEL: Assigning a sticker/label to a row

Tags: excel, tags

I am looking for a way, how to add an optional labels/stickers assigned to each row in excel to use filter based on specific sticker. The important part of the task is to find solution with the use of multiple stickers in one row.

An example of one row:
data | data | data | sticker1, sticker5

I can use a words separated by comma and create a filter based on used words but I hope I'll find more elegant solution.

Thank you.

Comment: You could use some sort of a bar code (sticker 1 & sticker 5 would be: 10001) and then use that going forward, no?

Comment: That is good idea and I haven't find anything better. 

This have to be supported by some script working with the numbers (generating, reading, searching) and it is not user friendly (it cannot be seen instantly). I suppose it will be hard to use standard excel filters; I wouldn't know, what I am filtering.